# Concept of Hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the concept of Planes and Hyperplanes.
The equation Ax+By+Cz=D where the D is a scalar and A, B,and C are the coefficients.  Any multiples of the entire equation also lie in the same plane.
Question: I believe the left side of the equation refers to the incline. Am I right? If yes, then what does the right side of the equation represent? Or should I assume the entire equation (Ax+By+Cz+D=0) represents the incline?

I wish there was a video by 3Blue1Brown regarding the hyperplanes.

Comment: What do you mean by incline?

Comment: I think he means slope.

Comment: Yes I meant slope

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x}=p$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ describes a $(d-1)$-dimensional hyperplane. (The word "hyperplane" typically refers to an affine subspace of codimension $1$, i.e. one less dimension than the ambient space.) Assuming $\mathbf{n}$ is normalized to be a unit vector, the hyperplane is the same as $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x}=0$ (whose solution set is the orthogonal complement of the $1$D line spanned by $\mathbf{n}$) but translated $p$ units in the direction of $\mathbf{n}$ (or backwards if $p$ is negative).